# The authorization server does not support obtaining a token using this method

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on, token

I am using ORY Hydra as authorization server and I'm trying to get an id_token along with the access_token when calling the authorize endpoint.

This is how my client is created

```
docker run --rm oryd/hydra clients create --audience my-aud -c http://localhost:3000 -g implicit --id test_token -n "Test getting an id_token" -a api,offline,openid -r id_token,token --token-endpoint-auth-method client_secret_post --endpoint http://10.1.0.147:4445
```

Now if I call my client using response_type=token, I can get only access token in the response

```
http://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth?client_id=test_token&login_verifier=dfb81eed26cf46f2832701f478c90d38&nonce=t12123421342313&provider=test&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&response_type=token&scope=api+openid+offline&state=xkm6tilq8ol7toxrib4ipxj6rckeen8kf
```

I get the response

```
#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzpmNTNhODI5Yi0wODFiLTQyMWItOTY3MS1kZWVkOGJlMTIxYzkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOlsiYXVkLWFwaSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJjb3JldGVjaF9jbGllbnQiLCJleHAiOjE1NjQwOTA3NDUsImV4dCI6eyJzdWJfaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1NjQwODcxNDUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQ0NC8iLCJqdGkiOiJmZTA3Y2JjMC00Y2FiLTRkNjktYmNlYS05MzRhNzNhOTkxMzYiLCJuYmYiOjE1NjQwODcxNDUsInNjcCI6WyJhcGlfc2NvcGUiXSwic3ViIjoiOTU3ZTA4ZjYtZTgyMy00ZTBjLThkODAtZDU3NTM2NmNhYTgxIn0.r97Vp_tmVOMpar3OSiOhNEI6PxzLoKtHE6CEezVsteamf7_qOhP6pbIvW91D8EZutGUuG4sxaDpunNv22R9hVyIGqVHqssAPLk5k7f00_UNp4ZuSswHqPj7L1O2JOp6zx-Ybrs_XTy3qaH9Yt-ofB35Y95DTyIabTIbuCyz2q24soWbf7j3yhseU6OJYq66qnw2PyhhskUKlLiaWcapioH4vnKJwg2aq1G_NKTGnuM3-w7XjR0TWVUBk9UDYDl4yo_eZJ5gA71ew6g44eO-ubdpjS1ITbsS5Dda8-R8jvmooHnr8uS3yJ5vATnwgNMfSEwBMEvodeWLloj9w0pDUaj8-9X6MDDxXMitBYjRgMulQUc2J-bkZM0_I0V6gyrj2NY_T3wDR6vbDvGG9n2J-KRbzIp1UE3c_LOfeUyW0xNEksBTJkFBIcS5BY0L_PE8rdGeyJ9iHEIBpWYA7MZKymu2-o9qoBa_kTzMTKj_v98c_BEnnKs7-F1WqecO-YP6pPKX9rTBQhe-pf4iC4yeObngkPIcJE5j_TQlTyUwyW5LZJN2xJglGugeuAdS2LMh0MNuaeaFGttOobOS2pUaIbgdvKxV2oV3fxWPh5h8a7iEsJC4VD75CApQIc5l6EeMaHRLN2mAIodRP-Mae6ht9556X4ghloZ50v-WczGAvq3I&expires_in=3599&scope=api&state=n3vxns17tfx7xpkkm5v9dw0bb6565s8&token_type=bearer
```

However, If I include the id_token now within the authorize endpoint parameters

```
http://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth?client_id=test_token&login_verifier=dfb81eed26cf46f2832701f478c90d38&nonce=t12123421342313&provider=test&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&response_type=id_token&scope=api+openid+offline&state=xkm6tilq8ol7toxrib4ipxj6rckeen8kf
```

After consenting, I get the following error

```
?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=The+authorization+server+does+not+support+obtaining+a+token+using+this+method&state=k3g94uqdy5ippyakeohsrwkpkrm1uh
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**error=unsupported_response_type**

It means your requested response type is not supported by ory/hydra Openid Connect provider.

And checking their [GIT repository](https://github.com/ory/hydra), [it is certified](https://github.com/ory/hydra#openid-connect-certified) only for following profiles,

> The following OpenID profiles are certified:
>
> - Basic OpenID Provider (response types code)
> - Implicit OpenID Provider (response types id_token, id_token+token)
> - Hybrid OpenID Provider (response types code+id_token,    code+id_token+token, code+token)

So you need to change your response type accordingly to match what they support.

Anyway please be mindful about Implicit and Hybrid flows. Though they are defined by OpenID Connect specification, they are not recommended to use. Instead go with authorisation code flow (basic openid provider as per above description.)

Comment: I'm using response_type =id_token, which is supported for the implicit flow and yet I still get that error..

Basically when you do response_type = token or id_token, it means that you are using implicit flow. But id_token gets refused..

Comment: @Ziko may be this is a bug on their end. did you try to report this ?